# SUMIFS across a range of sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm building an excel home finances/budget workbook.  I would like to keep the transactions for each account on separate sheets with my budget sheet separate from those.  I was looking for a way to sum the categories without hard-coding the names of the sheets used.  I setup the sheets as follows.

Budget - Start - Account1 - Account2 - End

I have more accounts to add once i get it working.  This is all prototyping to make sure I can do what I want.

I found I can do the following to sum everything on all sheets between Start and End (as long as those are blank).

```
=SUM(Start:End!B1:B10)
```

What I can't get working is a SUMIFS

```
=SUMIFS(Start:End!B1:B10,Start:End!A1:A10,"Count")
```

In column A a cell that has "Count" or "Don't".  These will eventually become categories. The above gives me a "#VALUE" error. I wasn't able to get SUMIF to work either.  I may add other conditions down the road.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is there an easy way to do something like this?

Comment: What is `Start:End`? A Sheet Name?

Comment: Start:End!B1:B10 will get every B1:B10 on sheets "Start", "Account1", "Account2" and "End" or any other sheet between the two.

Comment: Try wrapping in SUMPRODUCT.

Comment: If that does not work Google 3d SUMIFS. There are examples on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by making a Range E2:E4 containing the names of the sheets, the first being "Start" and the last being "End".

I also have a criteria box E7 with value "Count"

Start

[image: 1]

I've populated columns A1:A10 with either "Count" or "Don't".
I've populated columns B1:B10 with numbers.

Sheet2(left) and End(right)

[image: 2]

Then I used this formula to return the desired result:

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&E2:E4&"'!A1:A10"),E7,INDIRECT("'"&E2:E4&"'!B1:B10")))`

Don't know if that helps you but it does produce the desired results with the extra work of writing up a sheet list and a criteria list.

Comment: I'll give this a try.  Wish there was a way to avoid writing up the sheet names.

Comment: This seems to be working properly as long as E2:E4 all have sheet names.

Comment: Is there a way to remove empty values from array formulas? So I could leave a section for sheets (account names) that could be added to easily.

Comment: is there a way to get this to work on Google Sheets? It's only pulling values from the first sheet in my list of sheets (e2 in this case)